# what is the meaning for _paravirt_alt(insn_string, "%c[paravirt_typenum]", "%c[paravirt_clobber]")

Tags: linux, kernel, virtual-machine

I compiled paravirt_types.h in linux kernel and know " call *%c[paravirt_opptr];"  is calling function pointer, but I never see these two sentence syntax in GAS assembly and GCC manual ,

```
1, call *%c[paravirt_opptr]
2 #define paravirt_type(op)             \///
    [paravirt_typenum] "i" (PARAVIRT_PATCH(op)),    \  // ,, What is paravirt_typenum    ???
    [paravirt_opptr] "i" (&(op))                     ///whats is    %c[paravirt_opptr]    ??
```

I appreciate if you can help me for these two question ?